# ChartJS: datalabels: Show both numbers and percentages on a pie chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using ChartJS for my react application. I need to show both number and percentage on my pie piece(ex: 5(6.7%)). By using following code i'm getting only percentage. How do I show both? Thank you.

```
const data = {
    labels: ['America', 'China', 'Dubai', 'India'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Work Orders',
        data: [10, 50, 5, 2],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#00CF9B',
          '#E55B5E',
          '#FFD366',
          '#5A9ED4',
        ],
        borderWidth: 0,
      },
    ],
  };

  const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'right'
      },
      datalabels: {
        color: 'black',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        },
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          let sum = 0;
          let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
          dataArr.map(data => {
            sum += data;
          });
          let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2) + "%";
          return percentage;
        },
      }
    }
  }

<Pie data={data} options={options} />
```

Comment: Maybe by "return percentage + '(' +value+')' ;" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could add the value as part of the returned value of the callback.

Furthermore, using a doughnut/pie controller, you can access to the dataset meta data where you have already the total value therefore you could avoid to sum all values everytime.

```js
const data = {
    labels: ['America', 'China', 'Dubai', 'India'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Work Orders',
        data: [10, 50, 5, 2],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#00CF9B',
          '#E55B5E',
          '#FFD366',
          '#5A9ED4',
        ],
        borderWidth: 0,
      },
    ],
  };

  const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'right'
      },
      datalabels: {
        display: 'auto',
        color: 'black',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        },
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          const total = ctx.chart.getDatasetMeta(0).total;
          let percentage = (value * 100 / total).toFixed(2) + "%";
          return percentage + '(' + value + ')';
        },
      }
    }
  }

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  data,
  options
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@latest/dist/chart.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.2.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```